# Highcharts with data populated by php generated html table - only one will load

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I have a program that I've built using php/mysql where the user can choose different options at the beginning, such as to compare data from a specific date range or to compare year by year data by selecting which years to compare. Once the user chooses an option and either inputs the date range or selects what years to compare, I use php to pull the data from a mysql database and display it in html tables. All of the html is generated with php.

I have Highcharts set up to use the data from the html tables to generate a chart by including a set of functions beneath the php block. The problem is, the chart function I put first will generate while the ones below wont.

For example, when I put the date range charts first in the script, those charts will generate on the page when a user selects the date range option. But if they select the year-by-year option, that chart won't show up. If I switch the order of the chart functions in the script then when a user selects the date range functions they get all the html tables but no chart, while if they select the year-by-year option the chart shows up fine.

Something is conflicting in my code but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Can anyone help?

```
<?php
if ($option == 'opt1') {
print "<div id='hour_chart' style='height:400px;width:100%;'></div>";
print "<div id='hour_data'><strong>Body Counts by Hour</strong>";
print "<table class='results_table table2excel' id='byhour'>";
print "<thead><tr><th>Hour</th>";
print $hour1a;
print "</tr></thead><tbody>";
print "<tr><th>Range 1</th>" . $hour1b . "</tr>";
print "</tbody></table><br><br><br></div>";
print "<button  class='submitex' onclick=\"tablesToExcel(['rangeTable','byhour','byday','bymonth','bylocation'], ['DateRangeTotals','CountsByHour','CountsByDay','CountsByMonth','CountsByLocation'], 'BodyCounts.xls', 'Excel')\">Export to Excel</button>";
}
if ($option == 'opt2') {
print "<div id='year_chart' style='height:400px;width:100%;'></div>";
print "<div id='year_data'><strong>Body Counts by Academic Year</strong>";
print "<table class='results_table table2excel' id='byyear'>";
print "<thead><tr>";
print $ay1;
print "</tr></thead><tbody>";
print "<tr>" . $ay2 . "</tr>";
print "</tbody></table><br><br><br></div>";
print "<button class='submitex' onclick=\"tablesToExcel(['byyear'], ['CountsByAcademicYear'], 'BodyCounts.xls', 'Excel')\">Export to Excel</button>";
}
?>

<script>
$(function () { 
    Highcharts.chart('year_chart', {
    data: {
        table: 'byyear',
        switchRowsAndColumns: true
    },
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Body Counts by Academic Year'
    },
    colors: ['#272264','#6AF9C4'],
     yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        title: {
            text: 'Counts'
        }
    },
       tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                this.point.name.toLowerCase() + '<br>' + this.point.y;
        }
    }
});
});
$(function () { 
    Highcharts.chart('hour_chart', {
    data: {
        table: 'byhour',
        switchRowsAndColumns: true
    },
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Body Counts by Hour'
    },
    colors: ['#005481','#ED561B'],
    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        title: {
            text: 'Counts'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                this.point.name.toLowerCase() + '<br>' + this.point.y;
        }
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: why do you use `print` to render HTML? you could just use HTML out of PHP scriptlet

Comment: I'm still fairly new to php - print is just what I learned to use. I'm not familiar with php scriptlet, but would that potentially solve the issue I'm having?

Comment: Are you getting any Javascript errors? Check the console and post any error messages in the question. Also creating a working example in CodePen or JsFiddle really helps people here to see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know all you code but I don't see how `$option` could be equal to 2 different values - `opt1` and `opt2` - in the same time so you can change your javascript code to not generate an error like this :

```
<script>
<?php if ($option == 'opt2') : ?>
$(function () { 
    Highcharts.chart('year_chart', {
    data: {
        table: 'byyear',
        switchRowsAndColumns: true
    },
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Body Counts by Academic Year'
    },
    colors: ['#272264','#6AF9C4'],
     yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        title: {
            text: 'Counts'
        }
    },
       tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                this.point.name.toLowerCase() + '<br>' + this.point.y;
        }
    }
});
<?php elseif ($option == 'opt1') : ?>
});
$(function () { 
    Highcharts.chart('hour_chart', {
    data: {
        table: 'byhour',
        switchRowsAndColumns: true
    },
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Body Counts by Hour'
    },
    colors: ['#005481','#ED561B'],
    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        title: {
            text: 'Counts'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                this.point.name.toLowerCase() + '<br>' + this.point.y;
        }
    }
});
});
<?php endif; ?>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Core972 said, you can also decide which HTML elements you want to display. Exemplary `index.php` file:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script>    
        <?php
        $option = "opt1";
        ?>

        <?php if($option == "opt1") { ?>
            $(function () {
                Highcharts.chart('hour_chart', {
                    //data: {
                    //    table: 'byhour',
                    //    switchRowsAndColumns: true
                    //},
                    chart: {
                        type: 'column'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Body Counts by Hour'
                    },
                    colors: ['#005481','#ED561B'],
                    yAxis: {
                        allowDecimals: false,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Counts'
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                                this.point.name.toLowerCase() + '<br>' + this.point.y;
                        }
                    },
                    // dummy data
                    series: [{
                        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                    }]
                });
            });
        <?php } elseif($option == "opt2") { ?>
        $(function () { 
            Highcharts.chart('year_chart', {
                //  data: {
                //      table: 'byyear',
                //      switchRowsAndColumns: true
                //  },
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Body Counts by Academic Year'
                },
                colors: ['#272264','#6AF9C4'],
                yAxis: {
                    allowDecimals: false,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Counts'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                            this.point.name.toLowerCase() + '<br>' + this.point.y;
                    }
                },
                // dummy data
                series: [{
                    data: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
                }]
            });
        });
        <?php } ?>
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php if($option == "opt1") { ?>
            <div id='hour_chart' style='height:400px;width:100%;'></div>
            <div id='hour_data'><strong>Body Counts by Hour</strong>
                <table class='results_table table2excel' id='byhour'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Hour</th>
                            <!-- print $hour1a; -->
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Range 1</th>
                            <!-- " . $hour1b . " -->
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <br><br><br>
            </div>
            <button  class='submitex' onclick=\"tablesToExcel(['rangeTable','byhour','byday','bymonth','bylocation'], ['DateRangeTotals','CountsByHour','CountsByDay','CountsByMonth','CountsByLocation'], 'BodyCounts.xls', 'Excel')\">Export to Excel</button>
        <?php } elseif($option == "opt2") { ?>
            <div id='year_chart' style='height:400px;width:100%;'></div>
            <div id='year_data'><strong>Body Counts by Academic Year</strong>
                <table class='results_table table2excel' id='byyear'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <!-- print $ay1; -->
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <!-- " . $ay2 . " -->
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <br><br><br>
            </div>
            <button class='submitex' onclick=\"tablesToExcel(['byyear'], ['CountsByAcademicYear'], 'BodyCounts.xls', 'Excel')\">Export to Excel</button>
        <?php } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```